# EF5 one to many navigation property mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I searched and searched and could not find anything that answers my question.

I've got the following entities:

```
public class Item
{
   public int ItemID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int? NavID { get; set; }
   public ICollection<NavJamMap> NavJamMaps { get; set; }
}

public class Nav
{
  public int NavID { get; set; }
  // stuff
}

public class Jam
{
  public int JamID { get; set; }
  // stuff
}

public class NavJamMap
{
  public int NavID { get; set; }
  public int JamID { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
  public Nav Nav { get; set; }
  public Jam Jam { get; set; }
}
```

With the following fluent mappings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasKey(i => i.ItemID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(i => i.NavJamMaps)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.JamID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Nav>().HasKey(n => n.NavID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Jam>().HasKey(j => j.JamID);
modelBuilder.Entity<NavJamMap>.HasKey(m => new { m.NavID, m.JamID });
```

Basically, I want to be able to select:

```
var item = ctx.Items.Where(i => i.NavJamMaps.Any(m => m.JamID == 10)).FirstOrDefault()
```

but it generates SQL like the following:

```
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[NavJamMap] AS [Extent47]
    WHERE ([Project20].[ItemID] = [Extent47].[NavID]) AND 
          ([Extent47].[JamID] = @p__linq__2)
)
```

How can I change my fluent mapping to allow me to generate the correct SQL. I want to join with the NavID property on the Item entity and find all of the Jams corresponding to that NavID in an ICollection.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is wrong with generated SQL? It does exactly what you specified with LINQ query

Comment: `[Project20].[ItemID] = [Extent47].[NavID]` Nav and Item are two different tables and they're being matched incorrectly. It should say `[Project20].[NavID] = [Extent47].[NavID]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're going to need two foreign key relationships: a one-to-many (item-> nav) AND a many-to-many (nav<-->jam). The mappings between Nav/jam shouldnt have anything to do with the items.

Here's how I'd set it up:

Change the Item class to just have a FK to a Nav

```
public class Item
{
   public int ItemID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int? NavID { get; set; }
   public Nav? Nav { get; set; }
}
```

Then set the many>many FK in Nav and Jam classes

```
public class Nav
{
    public ICollection<Jam> Jams {get;set;}
}

public class Jam
{
    public ICollection<Nav> Navs {get;set;}
}
```

Then set up the Fluent mappings for both relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional(x => x.Nav).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.NavID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Nav>().HasMany<Jam>(x => x.Jams).WithMany(x => x.Navs).Map( x =>
{
    x.MapLeftKey("JamID");
    x.MapRightKey("NavID");
    x.ToTable("NavJamMap");
});
```

**EDIT! UPDATE!**

Just saw you wanted the creation time for the nav2jam table. Unfortunately there's no way to do that with the standard EF many-many EntityConfiguration. However, you can create a separate junction table with two separate one-many relationships.

```
public class Nav
{
    public virtual ICollection<NavJamMap> NavJamMaps {get;set;}
}
public class Jam
{
    public virtual ICollection<NavJamMap> NavJamMaps {get;set;}
}

public class NavJamMap
{
    public int NavID {get;set;}
    public int JamID {get;set;}
    public Nav Nav {get;set;}
    public Jam Jam {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate {get;set;}
}
```

Then use the mapping :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NavJamMap>().HasKey(x => new { x.NavID, x.JamID });
```

Comment: Thanks Dustin. I thought I'd have to do something like this, I was trying to avoid it but I guess there is no other way.

Comment: Was this a solution to your question? if so, can you upvote or mark it as correct?

Comment: sorry, i was trying other solutions, but yes in the end, this was the only thing that worked -- i knew about this but did not want to modify either nav or jam. again, thanks!